# how do I do I solve this equation

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial

(n+1)! = 110(n-1)!

I have searched online for a week now and my textbook does not explain how it got the answer: n=10.

Comment: You have searched the web for the answer to an equation? Wouldn't be more useful to try to understand the different parts of the equation and then make some attempts to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Write out what those factorials mean:

$$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (n-2)(n-1)(n)(n+1) = 110 \cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (n-2)(n-1).$$

What can you cancel from both sides?

Answer (score 0):

$$(n+1)!=110(n-1)!$$
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-1)!}=110$$
$$\frac{(n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)...(3)(2)(1)}{(n-1)(n-2)...(3)(2)(1)}=110$$
$$(n+1)(n)=110$$

You could expand this into a quadratic and solve or simply see that the only two consecutive positive integers whose product is 110 are 10 and 11. So $n=10, n+1=11, 10\cdot11=110$.